# busybox shell script - unknown operand error message

Tags: shell-script, scripting, python, busybox

I need to write a small shell script that will execute a python script and get the results.

When I try to run it this way it works:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/python /etc/scripts/backup.py
result=$?

if [ $result -gt 0 ];
    then echo 'PROBLEM';
else
    echo 'OK';
fi
```

But if I try to do it this way, it fails:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $(/usr/bin/python /etc/scripts/backup.py) -gt 0 ];
    then echo 'PROBLEM';
else
    echo 'OK';
fi
```

It returns:

```
lab-1:/etc/scripts# ./audit_test_wrapper.sh
sh: 0: unknown operand
OK
```

And the results are wrong.  It should be printing "PROBLEM"" instead of OK.

**what I've tried so far**

```
if [ $(/usr/bin/python /etc/scripts/backup.py) -ne 0 ];
```

returns

```
lab-1:/etc/scripts# ./audit_test_wrapper.sh
sh: 0: unknown operand
OK
```

And I also tried this:

```
if [ "$(/usr/bin/python /etc/scripts/backup.py)" -gt 0 ];
```

it returns:

```
lab-1:/etc/scripts# ./audit_test_wrapper.sh
sh: out of range
OK
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A command does not return its exit status (`$?`) on standard output.  A command substitution (`$(...)`) captures the standard output.

Instead, just do

```
#!/bin/sh

if ! /usr/bin/python /etc/scripts/backup.py; then
   echo 'PROBLEM'
else
   echo 'OK'
fi
```

This would pick the first branch and print `PROBLEM` if the python script exited with a non-zero exit status.

You may read the `if` statement as "If the script did not succeed".

If you want to get rid of the `!`:

```
#!/bin/sh

if /usr/bin/python /etc/scripts/backup.py; then
   echo 'OK'
else
   echo 'PROBLEM'
fi
```

You may read the `if` statement as "If the script did succeed".

---

The *error* that you get comes from the fact that the script doesn't output anything, which means that the command substitution will be empty.  Since it's unquoted, the command that the shell will try to execute will look like

```
if [ -gt 0 ]
```

This is a syntax error.

When quoting the command substitution, you essentially try to run

```
if [ "" -gt 0 ]
```

and the shell is not able to compare the empty string as an integer.

Answer (score 2):

As Kusalananda shows, you just need to use

```
if cmd; then
    echo "command succeeded"
else
    echo "command failed: $?"
fi
```

In a more illustrative example, you can run commands like this to see how exit codes of non-zero are "false" and a 0 exit code is true for 'if', 'while' and other logical comparisons in shell command structures.

```
$ if (exit 3); then echo succeeded ; else echo failed $?;fi
failed 3
$ if (exit 0); then echo succeeded ; else echo failed $?;fi
succeeded
$
```

The while loop works as shown below:

```
$ i=3;while ! (exit $i); do echo failed $i; ((i--));done
failed 3
failed 2
failed 1
$
```

This can be used to retry a command that fails to connect, or otherwise needs a retry until it succeeds.

The use of (exit ...) runs that command as a separate process.  For built in shell commands, this is required to keep the shell instance running your script from exiting.  Instead, a sub-process is created by the shell, and it's exit code provides the value of $? as shown in the shell man page.